# Variable Capturing With Repetition of Variable Name

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am very confused as to which variables are captured by which λ in the example below:

```
(λa.λb.(λa.a)aba)(ab)
```

I am new to lambda calculus and the repetition of variables makes this example hard for me to understand and reduce. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the construction tree of the expression, a variable  $x$ of a leaf refers to that $\lambda x$ which is closest to $x$ in the path from $x$ to the root.

Another way to see it is with the use of scoping rules. The scope of each $\lambda$ is the body of the $\lambda$.

So, the scope of the inner-most $\lambda a$ is only $a$. This means that any occurrence of $a$ outside that parenthesis refers to a different variable than the $a$ inside the parenthesis (point 1).

The scope of the $\lambda b$ is $(λa.a)aba$, so similarly any $b$ outside this expression refers to a different variable (that just happens to have the same name).

The scope of the outermost $\lambda a$ is $\lambda b.(\lambda a.a)aba$. Here things are a bit more complex, because there's another $\lambda a$ inside. But according to point (1) the $a$ in $\lambda a.a$ is different than the $a$'s in the rest of the body. So, only the $a$'s in $aba$ refer to the outermost $\lambda a$.

Note that there are no lambda's to bind the $a$ and $b$ in subexpression $(ab)$ (on the right of the expression). Therefore, the $a$ and $b$ in $(ab)$ occur free.